# overriding toString but still using it to do the work

Tags: java, inheritance, tostring

I'm working on an assignment and I have to create a parent class that another class extends and I have to over ride the toString() method in the parent class and use the parent toString method to display the new one, but add a line.

All that I'm fine with, but where I'm stuck, the original toString() has a number format object that formats a double into money, and I need a double formatted in the new line. The instructions say I should not need a number formatter in the new toString method, and to let the old toString() method handle "most of the work" but I can't figure out how it is possible to format this double.

Here's some code so you can see what I mean:

```
    import java.text.NumberFormat;

    public abstract class First {

    public First(int x, double y)

    protected int num = x;
    protected double num2 = y;
    }

    public String toString()
    {   
        NumberFormat x = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        return "Int num: " + num + 
             "\n     num2: " + x.format(num2);

    }
    }
```

Then I have the child class:

```
public class Second extends First {

protected double num3;

public Second(int x, double y, double z) 
{
 super(x, y);
 num3 = z

}

public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + "\n num3 " + num3; 
}
```

}

If I do this (I left out a lot of irrelevant code) it works, but I need num3 to be formatted like money, like num2 is in the parent class but I can't have a formatter object in the child class.

If someone could push me in the right direction, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You could separate the Formatting from the `toString()` method in your parent class then use this in your child like:

In First

```
protected String formatNum(double number)
{
    NumberFormat x = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    return x.format(number); 
}

public String toString()
{   
    return "Int num: " + num + 
         "\n     num2: " + formatNum(num2);
}
```

Then in second

```
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + "\n num3 " + formatNum(num3); 
}
```

**EDIT** An alternative is to have the `NumberFormat` Object as part of the `First` Object then initialise in in the constructor

```
public abstract class First {

    protected int num;
    protected double num2;    
    protected NumberFormat f;

    public First(int x, double y)
    {
        num = x;
        num2 = y;
        f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    }

    public String toString()
    {   
        return "Int num: " + num + 
             "\n     num2: " + f.format(num2);
    }
}
```

Then just use that in `Second`

```
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + "\n num3 " + f.format(num3); 
}
```

Comment: If desired you could make `formatNum` `protected` instead of `public`; the child class `Second` will still be able to use it, but it won't become a public method visible to every other class.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about making it a separate method but it seems like he wants something else because he laid out all the other methods we're supposed to have, and formatting methods weren't in there. It seems like that's the best solution though.This teacher is very vague about his expectations. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ajb Good point, should probably be protected. @insomnius The other option would be to have the `NumberFormat` as part of the `First` Object, See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Without having checked, NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() probably returns a singleton and therefore calling it as the parent does, would not result in another object but the same one as the parent uses... Maybe a fun question :).